# How to setup a gitlab-ci mysql service with a dependant flyway migration service?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need a Gitlab CI setup for integration tests with a mysql database (plain mysql image) and a dedicated flyway migration (custom docker image). Therefore I tried to define mysql as a service and my custom docker image as a service. For some reason flyway is unable to connect to the MySQL database (maybe because it is started before the MySQL db is ready for connections).

I am migrating from Travis CI to the free Gitlab CI version (shared runner). In Travis CI I used a docker-compose file to run the db, waited for it to be reachable, then ran the flyway migrations and after that my integration tests connected to the MySQL db.

Please note, that the flyway migrations are in a dedicated docker image for a reason. I know that my issue would be solvable by merging flyway into the mysql image or merging it into the application itself. However there are technical reasons in my use case not to do so.

Alternative steps I tried so far:

- Spinning up mysql db and flyway manually with docker:dind. While this works, I am unable to connect to the mysql db from my integration tests. This seems to be a limitation of docker in docker.
- Running the flyway migrations manually with docker:dind against a mysql service. In this case flyway cannot connect to the mysql service as they are in different networks.

I have created a micro example where I am trying to run a simple flyway migration against a plain MySQL database. It's a bit recursive the docker image needs to be build once first.
You can see the code here: https://gitlab.com/Brutus5000/gitlab-services-test.

The gitlab-ci.yml is the following:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind
  - mysql:5.7
  - name: registry.gitlab.com/brutus5000/gitlab-services-test:dev
    command: ["migrate"]

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/brutus5000/gitlab-services-test
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
  FLYWAY_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql/test?useSSL=false
  FLYWAY_USER: root
  FLYWAY_PASSWORD: test

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --tag $CONTAINER_IMAGE:dev .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:dev
```

The dockerfile is a simple addition to the base flyway image:

```
FROM boxfuse/flyway:5.2.0-alpine

ENV FLYWAY_EDITION community

COPY migrations /flyway/sql/
```

I would expect to see the flyway migrations happen in the pipeline log. Instead I see this error:

https://gitlab.com/Brutus5000/gitlab-services-test/-/jobs/139577852

> *** WARNING: Service runner-72989761-project-10117031-concurrent-0-registry.gitlab.com__brutus5000__gitlab-services-test-2 probably didn't start properly.
>
> Health check error:
>   exit code 1
>
> Health check container logs:
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.592931651Z No HOST or PORT
>
> Service container logs:
>   2018-12-28T12:35:49.751790056Z Flyway Community Edition 5.2.0 by Boxfuse
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942865457Z ERROR: 
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942913738Z Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://mysql/test?useSSL=false) for user 'root': Communications link failure
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942919338Z 
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942922129Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942925648Z ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942929549Z SQL State  : 08S01
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942932188Z Error Code : 0
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942934751Z Message    : Communications link failure
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942937423Z 
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942939881Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   2018-12-28T12:35:50.942943453Z

---